# Image quality lost Using Next/Image NEXT JS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm building an webapp using nextjs 13, and suddenly i had see that my images los quality
and i dont know why or what i miss or did wrong

but when i inspect the html element on the browser i see this

```
   <img alt="product" loading="lazy" decoding="async" data-nimg="fill" sizes="50px" srcset="/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsunset.com.py%2Fimg%2Fpattern%2Fgoodride%2F716%2Fgoodride_cr976a_01_l.jpg&amp;w=16&amp;q=75 16w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsunset.com.py%2Fimg%2Fpattern%2Fgoodride%2F716%2Fgoodride_cr976a_01_l.jpg&amp;w=32&amp;q=75 32w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsunset.com.py%2Fimg%2Fpattern%2Fgoodride%2F716%2Fgoodride_cr976a_01_l.jpg&amp;w=48&amp;q=75 48w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsunset.com.py%2Fimg%2Fpattern%2Fgoodride%2F716%2Fgoodride_cr976a_01_l.jpg&amp;w=64&amp;q=75 64w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsunset.com.py%2Fimg%2Fpattern%2Fgoodride%2F716%2Fgoodride_cr976a_01_l.jpg&amp;w=96&amp;q=75 96w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsunset.com.py%2Fimg%2Fpattern%2Fgoodride%2F716%2Fgoodride_cr976a_01_l.jpg&amp;w=128&amp;q=75 128w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsunset.com.py%2Fimg%2Fpattern%2Fgoodride%2F716%2Fgoodride_cr976a_01_l.jpg&amp;w=256&amp;q=75 256w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsunset.com.py%2Fimg%2Fpattern%2Fgoodride%2F716%2Fgoodride_cr976a_01_l.jpg&amp;w=384&amp;q=75 384w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsunset.com.py%2Fimg%2Fpattern%2Fgoodride%2F716%2Fgoodride_cr976a_01_l.jpg&amp;w=640&amp;q=75 640w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsunset.com.py%2Fimg%2Fpattern%2Fgoodride%2F716%2Fgoodride_cr976a_01_l.jpg&amp;w=750&amp;q=75 750w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsunset.com.py%2Fimg%2Fpattern%2Fgoodride%2F716%2Fgoodride_cr976a_01_l.jpg&amp;w=828&amp;q=75 828w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsunset.com.py%2Fimg%2Fpattern%2Fgoodride%2F716%2Fgoodride_cr976a_01_l.jpg&amp;w=1080&amp;q=75 1080w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsunset.com.py%2Fimg%2Fpattern%2Fgoodride%2F716%2Fgoodride_cr976a_01_l.jpg&amp;w=1200&amp;q=75 1200w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsunset.com.py%2Fimg%2Fpattern%2Fgoodride%2F716%2Fgoodride_cr976a_01_l.jpg&amp;w=1920&amp;q=75 1920w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsunset.com.py%2Fimg%2Fpattern%2Fgoodride%2F716%2Fgoodride_cr976a_01_l.jpg&amp;w=2048&amp;q=75 2048w, /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsunset.com.py%2Fimg%2Fpattern%2Fgoodride%2F716%2Fgoodride_cr976a_01_l.jpg&amp;w=3840&amp;q=75 3840w" src="/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsunset.com.py%2Fimg%2Fpattern%2Fgoodride%2F716%2Fgoodride_cr976a_01_l.jpg&amp;w=3840&amp;q=75" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; inset: 0px; color: transparent;">
```

when i change the sizes="50px" to 250px insisde teh browser its works, but i dont know why and where next do this atomaticly or what i did to this happens or what i have to configurate for avoid this
how can i solve it and why is this.

my image code:

```
 <Image
            width={500}
            height={500}
            quality={100}
            src={image}
            alt={name}
            className="absolute object-cover object-center"
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

i had solved using the property "sizes"

```
<Image
         
            quality={100}
            src={image}
            alt={name}
            className="absolute object-cover object-center"
            sizes="200px"
          />
```